# Formspree 400 BAD REQUEST form submission

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

[On my website](https://igorkowalczyk.github.io) I have a contact form that sends XHR requests to [Formspree](https://formspree.io) application but every time the request is sent [Formspree](https://formspree.io) returns error 400 (Bad request). I was looking for a solution but nothing solved my problem (the website is available at https://igorkowalczyk.github.io).If it wasn't my mistake you can write alternatives to Formspree, you can write alternatives to Formspree.

Here is my code:

```js
const contact = document.querySelector('.contact-form');
const contactinputs = document.querySelectorAll('.contact-input');
const nameinput = document.querySelector('.contact-input-name');
const emailinput = document.querySelector('.contact-input-email');
const messageinput = document.querySelector('.contact-input-message');
const nameerror = document.querySelector('.nameerror');
const emailerror = document.querySelector('.emailerror');
const messageerror = document.querySelector('.messageerror');
const sendfaileddiv = document.querySelector('.contact-sendfailed');
const sendsucceededdiv = document.querySelector('.contact-sendsucceeded');
const button = document.querySelector('.contact-form-btn');

function post(url, data, callback, errorcallback) {
  const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open('POST', url);
  xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
  xhr.onload = function() {
    if (xhr.status === 200) {
      callback(xhr.responseText);
    } else if (xhr.status !== 200) {
      errorcallback(xhr.responseText);
    }
  };
  xhr.send(encodeURI(data));
}

if (contact) {
  contact.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    sendfaileddiv.classList.remove("show-message");
    sendsucceededdiv.classList.remove("show-message");
    nameerror.classList.remove("show-message");
    emailerror.classList.remove("show-message");
    messageerror.classList.remove("show-message");
    const name = nameinput.value.trim();
    const email = emailinput.value.trim();
    const message = messageinput.value.trim();
    let error = false;
    let fatalerror = false;
    const messages = [];

    if (name.length < 2) {
      error = true;
      nameerror.classList.add("show-message");
    }
    if (email.search(/^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&’*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*$/) === -1) {
      error = true;
      emailerror.classList.add("show-message");
    }
    if (message.length < 2) {
      error = true;
      messageerror.classList.add("show-message");
    }
    if (fatalerror) {
      return false;
    }
    if (error) {
      return false;
    }
    const params = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < contactinputs.length; i++) {
      const input = contactinputs[i];
      params.push(`${ input.name }=${ input.value }`);
    }

    button.innerHTML = "Sending...";

    post(
      e.target.getAttribute('action'),
      params.join('&'),
      function(text) {
        contact.reset();
        sendsucceededdiv.classList.add("show-message");
        button.innerHTML = '<svg aria-hidden="true" role="img" class="button-svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 512 512"><path fill="currentColor" d="M476 3.2L12.5 270.6c-18.1 10.4-15.8 35.6 2.2 43.2L121 358.4l287.3-253.2c5.5-4.9 13.3 2.6 8.6 8.3L176 407v80.5c0 23.6 28.5 32.9 42.5 15.8L282 426l124.6 52.2c14.2 6 30.4-2.9 33-18.2l72-432C515 7.8 493.3-6.8 476 3.2z"></path></svg> Send';
      },
      function(text) {
        sendfaileddiv.classList.add("show-message");
        button.innerHTML = '<svg aria-hidden="true" role="img" class="button-svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 512 512"><path fill="currentColor" d="M476 3.2L12.5 270.6c-18.1 10.4-15.8 35.6 2.2 43.2L121 358.4l287.3-253.2c5.5-4.9 13.3 2.6 8.6 8.3L176 407v80.5c0 23.6 28.5 32.9 42.5 15.8L282 426l124.6 52.2c14.2 6 30.4-2.9 33-18.2l72-432C515 7.8 493.3-6.8 476 3.2z"></path></svg> Send';
      }
    );
  });
}
```

```html
<form class="contact-form" action="https://formspree.io/MY-FORMSPREE-ID" method="post">
  <p class="contact-form-title">Have any questions?</p>
  <fieldset class="field-name">
    <div class="wrap-input">
      <label for="name">Name
<div class="nameerror error">Please enter a name!</div>
<input class="contact-input-name" type="text" name="name" placeholder="John Doe" title="This field is required" maxlenght="50">
</label>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset class="field-email">
    <div class="wrap-input">
      <label for="email">E-Mail
<div class="emailerror error">Please enter a vaild email!</div>
<input class="contact-input-email" type="text" name="email" placeholder="john@doe.com" title="This field is required" maxlenght="50" spellcheck="false">
</label>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset class="field-message no-margin">
    <div class="wrap-input">
      <label for="message">Message
<div class="messageerror error">Please enter a message!</div>
<textarea class="contact-input-message no-margin" name="message" placeholder="Your message" title="This field is required" maxlenght="150" autocomplete="off" spellcheck="true"></textarea>
</label>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
  <div class="container-contact-form-btn submit">
    <button class="contact-form-btn"><svg aria-hidden="true" role="img" class="button-svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 512 512"><path fill="currentColor" d="M476 3.2L12.5 270.6c-18.1 10.4-15.8 35.6 2.2 43.2L121 358.4l287.3-253.2c5.5-4.9 13.3 2.6 8.6 8.3L176 407v80.5c0 23.6 28.5 32.9 42.5 15.8L282 426l124.6 52.2c14.2 6 30.4-2.9 33-18.2l72-432C515 7.8 493.3-6.8 476 3.2z"></path></svg> Send</button>
  </div>
  <div class="contact-sendfailed message">The message couldn't be sent, please try again later.</div>
  <div class="contact-sendsucceeded message">Thank you, your message has been sent!</div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you check the network tab you will see that no data is being passed to the server. If you walk through the code you will find that there are no elements in your `contactinputs` nodeList. This is because there are no elements with a class of `.contact-input` If you want to match elements with a classname that *starts* with "contact-input-" you have to do something like this:

```
const contactinputs = document.querySelectorAll('[class^="contact-input-"]');
```

Comment: I check console log and the Formspree JSON response error is `{"error":"Can't send an empty form"}` But the request parametrs is `name=Test&email=vaild-email&message=message`. I'm added to all inputs the `contact-input` class.